# Dependency injection, composition root, and entry points

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I've spent a lot of time reading these articles (along with many others):

- [Mark Seemann - Pure DI](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/)
- [Mark Seemann - When to use a DI Container](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/06/WhentouseaDIContainer/)
- [Mark Seemann - Compose object graphs with confidence](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/04/Composeobjectgraphswithconfidence/)
- [Mark Seemann - Don't call the container; it'll call you](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/08/30/Dontcallthecontainer;itllcallyou/)
- [Mark Seemann - Understanding the Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root)

and I'm still trying to wrap my head around DI and the concept of "wiring up the dependencies" and the "auto wiring" functionality of an IoC container.

I think I understand the theory of Dependency Injection and Inversion of Control and I've implemented the example shown here from 2016 (I updated the code to use [PSR-11](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-11/) and eliminate the need for the `container-interop` package):

- https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-your-own-dependency-injection-container/

The application of the container example is shown at the GitHub link: https://github.com/sitepoint-editors/Container .

Note that while this example uses PHP, I'm trying to understand the details of DI independently from language, so any language is welcome.

Can someone explain the difference between manually wiring up dependencies, and using a container's auto wiring functionality? The SitePoint article briefly mentions that more advanced containers add the automatic wiring functionality, implying that the example doesn't contain this function already. Can someone explain the application shown on the GitHub page and how that relates to core DI and IoC concepts, like the Composition Root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can someone explain the difference between manually wiring up dependencies, and using a container's auto wiring functionality?

Pure DI is the practice of applying DI without using a DI Container. This means that you build a graph of objects by newing up objects using the `new` construct of your programming language. See for instance this example in C# (from [listing 12.2](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-12/65) of Mark's book [Dependency Injection Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://cuttingedge.it/book/)):

```cs
new HomeController(
    new ProductService(
        new SqlProductRepository(
            new CommerceContext(connectionString)),
        new AspNetUserContextAdapter()));
```

According to that book, Auto-Wiring is:

> *the ability to automatically compose an object graph from maps between Abstractions and concrete types by making use of type information supplied by the compiler and the [runtime environment].* (see [12.1.2](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-12/section-12-1-2))

In other words, with a DI Container, you will be able to 'just' tell the container about your types, and it will figure out which dependencies a type has and will be able to 'wire' that type with its dependencies.

Considering the previous example, listing 12.3 shows how you only have to specify the mappings between abstractions and concrete types in a container:

```cs
var container = new AutoWireContainer();

container.Register(typeof(IUserContext), typeof(AspNetUserContextAdapter));
container.Register(typeof(IProductRepository), typeof(SqlProductRepository));
container.Register(typeof(IProductService), typeof(ProductService));
container.Register(typeof(CommerceContext), () => new CommerceContext(connectionString));
```

And when you ask for a `HomeController`, the container knows how to construct the entire graph.

> The SitePoint article briefly mentions that more advanced containers add the automatic wiring functionality

To me, Auto-Wiring is what makes a library into a DI Container. Something can't be called a DI Container if it doesn't, at the very least, support Auto-Wiring.

Comment: I'm still hung up on the term "wiring": does it refer to the act of object graph creation, either manually or automatically? Are the object graphs shown in those code excerpts implemented literally as a nested cascade of independent objects? For that object graph to start resolving, the innermost dependencies must then be manually provided with the necessary dependencies like `connectionString` from the first example. `connectionString` would then be something like a root dependency that has no other dependencies. Is this approximately correct?

Comment: "Wiring" is the same as "composing" the object graph; it refers to the creation of the graph, either manually or using a DI Container.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for the words but I couldn't find them. I'll extend my question concerning another point I wanted to raise that is related to this I think.

Comment: The Pure DI object graph, as shown in my answer, can really be implemented like that. But what the final code would look like is highly dependent on the structure of the rest of the application. When reuse of parts of the graph is required, you would see the creation of the graph split into pieces and placed into local variables. It all depends on context.

Comment: In the example from the book `connectionString` is a `string` type, which is pulled from a configuration file. This is a simple configuration value. A string has no dependencies of its own. We won't however, call it a "root" dependency. We typically consider the "roots" the classes that have no consumers. This string is a "leaf".

Comment: In Pure DI, how would you modify the object graph from listing 12.2 to handle multiple implementations for a given service?

Comment: That is not something I can answer without having much more context. It is highly dependant on the situation.

Comment: That's fair. I will see if I can pull a new question together to address that.

Comment: I think I have answered most of my questions by reading Mark's book. While it is tuned to .Net, the principles are well laid out for generic application. It also turns out I had (have) far more to learn about software architecture than I anticipated.