# PHP-DI container configuration

Tags: php, dependency-injection, php-di

This is a follow-on to my previous question (which was poorly scoped) which made me realize I had more I needed to learn about DI:

[Dependency injection, composition root, and entry points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59759128/dependency-injection-composition-root-and-entry-points)

1. Can someone explain what aspect of dependency injection and related concepts are taking place in the PHP-DI Demo? What is the configuration shown below even required if the container supports auto-wiring?

https://github.com/PHP-DI/demo

Specifically, I see that the demo appears to be using the default auto-wiring setting (i.e. enabled) but there is still configuration taking place such as the following

https://github.com/PHP-DI/demo/blob/master/app/config.php

```php
use function DI\create;
use SuperBlog\Model\ArticleRepository;
use SuperBlog\Persistence\InMemoryArticleRepository;
use Twig\Environment;
use Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader;

return [
    // Bind an interface to an implementation
    ArticleRepository::class => create(InMemoryArticleRepository::class),

    // Configure Twig
    Environment::class => function () {
        $loader = new FilesystemLoader(__DIR__ . '/../src/SuperBlog/Views');
        return new Environment($loader);
    },
];
```

2. Regarding DI and auto-wiring concepts specifically, what if I also had a `SQLArticleRepository` implementation of `ArticleRepository`? How would I be able to use a run time value to select between the type of repository?

Answer (score 0):

check the section
**Rules for using a container and dependency injection**
in this link http://php-di.org/doc/best-practices.html

You need to provide type-hinting which will let the di container know what implementation of the interface the function requires. Also you have to register/autowire that implementation in the di container as well.